# iPhone selects a Shift key when focusing on a HTML input field. How to turn this off?

Tags: iphone, html, input, keyboard

When I'm focus on an input field on an iPhone, the Shift key is turned on to make sure that the input starts with upper case. Is there a way to turn off this functionality and not have the Shift key when I focus on a field?

I understand why this might be good in some cases but in my case this is a user name or email field, most of which don't start with upper case letter.

**Update:** The answer lead me to [Safari Web Content Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/DesigningForms/DesigningForms.html) page which I'll be referencing more often from now on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve it by setting autocapitalize as off

```
<input type="text" name="test1" autocapitalize="off"/>
```

and also Set the autocorrect attribute of your textbox as off to turn off the auto correct feature.

```
<input type="text" name="test1" autocorrect="off"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a proprietary attribute for that: autocapitalize (on/off)

```
<input type="email" name="username" autocapitalize="off">
```

Please note that this is not a W3C standard and will result in invalid code.